# Modal updating data but throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to be able to update data in my modal, and have the updated data displayed in the table on close of the modal.

It is updating the db, but after it does it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError in Products#update
```

And highlights this line of code: and says that @products is nil

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```

This is all in index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid col-md-8">
<h1>Products</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed
sortable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><a>TITLE</a></th>
    <th><a>ASIN</a></th>
    <th><a>PRICE</a></th>
    <th> </th>
    <th><a>Toggle</a></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.title %></td>
      <td><%= link_to product.asin, "" %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', "" , :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', "" , :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you 
        sure?', :class => 'orange btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-remote="<%= edit_product_path(product) %>" #largeModal<%= 
        product.asin %> data-target="#largeModal<%= product.asin%>"
        >Click</a>
      </td>  
        <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal<%= product.asin %>" 
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" 
        aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Product: <%= product.asin %></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
                  <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <%= form_for product do |f| %>

                    <label>Title</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :title %>

                    <label>ASIN</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :asin %>

                    <%= f.submit "submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

                    <% end %>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

And then here is my HomeController

```
class HomeController < AuthenticatedController

def index
  @products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
  @home = @products
end

end
```

And my ProductsController:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @product = Product.new
end

def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    if @product.update(product_params)
        flash[:success] = "Updated Succesfully!"
        render 'home/index'

    else
      render 'shared/modal' #this is the same modal as a partial..
    end

end

    private
    def product_params
       params.require(:product).permit(:title, :asin)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when it renders the modal, `@products` is `nil`. You need to define it or `@products.each` can't work.

Could also be coming from the fact that you don't define anything for `params[:page]` when you render `home/index`.

Comment: Thats what I don't understand.. Because "@products" populates the table where the button is that kicks off the modal. Clueless how @products could be nil? Any idea how to fix?

Comment: When you render things the first time, `@products` is defined in the index action of your home controller. However, when you render things in your update action, @products never gets defined. When you do `render 'home/index'`, is there anything for `params[:page]`? And when you do `render 'shared/modal'`, there won't be anything for `@products` unless you specify it.

Comment: thanks for putting me in the right direction.. Actually updated the show action to redirect_to root_path.. and now its working fine..